DxTreeView custom node expansion on button click
I'm using the Blazor DevExpress DxTreeView component with a NodeTemplate for custom row rendering, and I would like to use this:
NodeExpandCollapseAction="TreeViewNodeExpandCollapseAction.ButtonClick"

for enabling the node expansion only on node icon click, but as the icon is rendered with HTML custom code in , this seems not working.
Any workaround for this?
